# Local variables in global scope Lua

Tags: lua, scope, global, local, love2d

So let's say I have a lua file, and at the top, I define a variable outside of any function, but I call it local

```
local x = 1
```

Is there any difference between that local x, and a global x?

Comment: You can't really define a variable outside of a function because a script is compiled as a [function body](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.2).

Answer (score 15):

Yes, as it is local to the [*chunk*](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.2) that it is created in.

> Lua handles a chunk as the body of an anonymous function with a variable number of arguments (see §3.4.11). As such, chunks can define local variables, receive arguments, and return values. Moreover, such anonymous function is compiled as in the scope of an external local variable called _ENV (see §2.2). The resulting function always has _ENV as its only upvalue, even if it does not use that variable.

Consider this example:

```
-- main.lua
require 'other'
print(x, y)
```

---

```
-- other.lua
local x = 5
y = 10
```

This will print out `nil, 10`, since `x` was local to the *chunk*, while `y` was assigned as an *upvalue* for whichever *environment* the *chunk* was loaded in.

See also:

- [§2.2 – Environments and the Global Environment](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.2)
- [§3.3.7 – Local Declarations](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.7)

And note that the semantics of *environments* changed between Lua5.1 and Lua5.2:

- [Lua 5.1: §2.9 – Environments](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.9)